# Firebase Cloud Messaging Token error but up to date token

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when I send push from device A to device B . Push fails with error:

```
404 {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

According to documentation this error occurs when FCM Token is not valid. However in delegate method didReceiveRegistrationToken I receive the same token which I use in the push, so FCM token is up to date. Or maybe I'm missing something. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Device B doesn't receive any push notification?

Comment: @StefanWang No, server cannot deliver it because of the error.